# I animated a short 110 frame clip but every time I export, the video is completely white. I'm using Cycles but I don't know why it's white

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I animated a shot for something I'm working on but when I render the animation (six hours to render for some reason) I'll check to find the video is just a white screen. I haven't had any problems with rendering before, It's just this project. Is it because I imported the map from somewhere else and it broke it? I'm unsure. [image: blender screenshot]
[image: video view]

here's a link to the blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WEYnqzOkgdNzYJY04qsHVMjBhaXigLoY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You've got some things hidden by turning off the eyeball icons. That doesn't hide them from the renderer. Is something sitting right in front of the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In compositing: connect your image from Render layers to denoise.

> Hint: Always make a render at least from one frame before rendering a
> movie. And by the way: you shouldn't render directly in a movie but
> render in PNG or any other picture format of your choice. So whenever
> Blender crasher you can resume rendering and safe tons of time.

Comment: So connect image to image? Render layers to denoise?

Comment: yes, exactly!!!

Comment: please click on the checkmark left to my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure if there's something else wrong but something isn't working still.

Comment: I could render your file after that. Pls tell me what’s happening.

Comment: I suppose I can just try to render with png's because I was still going with avi, but It would just stop like 24 frames in and act like it was done, and never saved any video to my computer.

Comment: Ok, but it’s not white anymore…so this question is actually solved. Maybe open another question with your „new“ problem.